# How we can use a set (defined in OPL) in script (CPLEX/execute)

Tags: set, cplex, opl

I defined a set like this in OPL/CPLEX

```
{string} S1={"a","b","c"};
{string} S2= S1 diff {"a"}; //which return S2={"b","c"};
```

then I want to do this in a script

```
execute {
`var m=Opl.item(S1,0);`    //which return a
```

`var S3=S1 diff {m};`     //or
`var S3=S1 Opl.diff {m};` //but it doesn't work
}

Actually I need the Opl set functions in cplex script such as diff inter union etc

How can I do it?

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2):

```
{string} S1={"a","b","c"};
{string} S2= S1 diff {"a"}; //which return S2={"b","c"}; 
{string} Sm;
{string} S3;
execute {
var m=Opl.item(S1,0);    //which return a
Sm.add(m);
S3=Opl.operatorDIFF(S1,Sm);
writeln(S3);
}
```

gives

```
{"b" "c"}
```